# c# assembly, friend assembly

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, internal

The definition for C# internal access modifier is 
internal: Accessible only within containing assembly or friend assemblies.
So my question is what is c# assembly? what does it mean to be within containing assembly or friend assemblies? Does it mean within same namespace or project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An assembly is (in general) a single `.dll` or `.exe` file.
A C# project (in general) compiles to a single assembly.

You can mark a friend assembly using the `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo(...)]` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. btw, what is the use of declaring a friend assembly?

Comment: @xinghua: If you want to make members that are visible only to one other assembly (eg, for unit tests)

Answer (score 2):

You define it [using the `InteralsVisibleToAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The assembly is `IL` code with `manifest` information (in case of `.NET`), which can be `DLL` or `EXE`. In this way, using a `manifest` information, one assembly can be declared as a *friend* of another one, so access `internal` dataypes too.

By using attribute `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo..]` you mark into the manifest of the assembly specified information,

Answer (score 1):

The assembly contains the intermediate code, resources, and the metadata for itself. We can have a look inside the assembly using the ildasm (Intermediate Language Disassembler) tool that comes as part of Visual Studio. To access it you need to open the Visual Studio Command Prompt and type ildasm.exe. This will launch a Windows application that you can use to explore any .Net application.

> > A friend assembly is an assembly that can access another assembly's Friend (Visual Basic) or internal (C#) types and members. If you
> >     identify an assembly as a friend assembly, you no longer have to mark
> >     types and members as public in order for them to be accessed by other
> >     assemblies. This is especially convenient in the following scenarios:
>
> - During unit testing, when test code runs in a separate assembly but requires access to members in the assembly being tested that are
>     marked as Friend (Visual Basic) or internal (C#).
> - When you are developing a class library and additions to the library are contained in separate assemblies but require access to
>     members in existing assemblies that are marked as Friend (Visual
>     Basic) or internal (C#).